# Personal image-based menu for android

Tags: android, image, menu

I'm quite new to android and have a questen concerning an personal menu.

I want to make several activities use one menu. So i created a `header.xml` file, which I include in all the activities. There are 4 images in the header, I want to make them clickable (which is no problem with the `android:onClick` function), and I want to show the user which activity is running.

So i want to replace the "activity 1" image with an "activity 1 active" image and so on. When clicking on "activity 3", the menu should use following images for example:

activity 1, activity 2, activity 3 ACTIVE, activity 4

Furthermore, the active images should not be clickabel, because this would refresh the page.

I would be happy about ideas how to solve it! (project should run with `android:minSdkVersion="8"`)

greets

Comment: what you have searched for this up till so far

Comment: i have searched for "personal android menu", "android image menu" and phrases like that on the internet, however i could not find what i'm looking for

Comment: it can be handled in different ways 
1- Tabbed Menu
2- Option Menu 
Now  google again and search according to these

Comment: I think both, tabbed menu and option menu are not what i'm looking for, as tabbed menus are not working with earlier android versions and an option menu is to mage the options like "settings" and so on!?

Comment: both will suit your scenario and both are working from your required SKD ver

Answer (score 0):

For showing the user that he is in which activity you can show a Long or short **Toast** message in OnCreate like

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome in activity 3",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And for Stop clicking function you can cancel the OnClick() of your button by using:

```
image3.setClickable(false);
```